# Ideas for infant bedding

Tags: infant, sleep, cosleeping

We have an active 10 month old, who sleeps soundly, but tends to roll a lot thereby hitting his head against the crib railings. Having a small apartment, we don't have much place  for a mattress on the floor, or a large sized crib. Co-sleeping is one option we consider, but we do find ourselves on either edge of the bed, in fear of trampling over the baby.

Does any one have any ideas on compact furniture options that can be used, which don't pose as a risk to a rolling infant? He isn't walking yet, so bed railings are not an option, since he can stand and topple over them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need any different solution than what you already have. He rolls around, and finds the boundaries. There's no harm in that; he won't get bruises or concussions from rolling in the crib.

A larger crib will only give him longer crib sides to hit his head on.

You might want to shop around for some **padding** on the inside of the crib; make sure it's something that is attached to the crib so that he can't become entangled.

Comment: I don't recommend padding; it's not very safe, and it doesn't really accomplish much.  The child isn't getting hurt, as Torben notes, so just let him roll.

Answer (score 5):

We cosleep and have never rolled on the baby.

We've done this since she was about 1 month old (up until then, she slept alone with her mother), and she's now 6 1/2 months old. It's really cosy, even though there are often interruptions to your sleep. The first nights were tricky, because of the fear of rolling on her, but eventually you just become aware of where the little one is and tend not to keep your space. Sometimes you end up on the edge of the bed, but most nights you can just hold your ground and sleep with the little one touching you with her hand (or kicking you in the kidneys).

I should note that most of this took place during warmer months, so we slept mostly without cover. The little one refuses to have covers.

A couple of tricks to ensure that you do not drag your  covers over the little one are: sleeping with your shoulder level with your baby's middle and have a separate quilt each. I do not imagine this is a problem with a 10 month old, as they are already very robust.

If you are obese, go to bed drunk, or take sleeping pills, then the risk that you will roll on the little one increases.

Comment: No. If you are drunk or take sleeping pills, then you have less automatic control over what you are doing in your sleep, and therefore you increase the chance of rolling on your little one.

Comment: I misread it as advice lol. 'If you are obese, go to bed drunk, or take sleeping pills' as in do this if you're obese. My bad. :)

Comment: Sounds like pretty bad advice. ;)